# Adding two UICollectionViews in a ViewController with stores programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Trying to jump ship from storyboards.  I'm trying to put two UIViewControllers into a view, and scroll horizontally.

So first, I go into app delegate

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds);
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    var homeViewController = ViewController()
    let shirtStore = ShirtStore()
    let pantStore = PantStore()
    homeViewController.shirtStore = shirtStore
    homeViewController.pantStore = pantStore

    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())


    return true
}
```

I'm not sure if I loaded that first homeViewController.

Then, in my ViewController I have:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, 
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {



let collectionViewShirts = UICollectionView()
let collectionViewPants = UICollectionView()
let collectionViewShirtsIdentifier = "CollectionViewShirtsCell"
let collectionViewPantsIdentifier = "CollectionViewPantsCell"

var shirtStore: ShirtStore!
var pantStore: PantStore!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Hanger"

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    collectionViewShirts.delegate = self
    collectionViewPants.delegate = self

    collectionViewShirts.dataSource = self
    collectionViewPants.dataSource = self

    self.view.addSubview(collectionViewShirts)
    self.view.addSubview(collectionViewPants)

    collectionViewShirts.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewShirtsCell")
}

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

if collectionView == self.collectionViewShirts {
        let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewShirtsIdentifier, for:  indexPath as IndexPath)

        // Set up cell
        cellA.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return cellA
    }

    else {
        let cellB = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewPantsIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath)

        // ...Set up cell
         cellB.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return cellB
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    if(collectionView == collectionViewShirts)
    {
        return shirtStore.allShirts.count
    }
    else if (collectionView == collectionViewPants)
    {

        return 5//pantStore.allPants.count
    }
    else
    {
        return 5//shoeStore.allShoes.count
    }
  }
}
```

My app is terminating due to a nil layout parameter.  What am I missing.  There are no warnings upon build.

Comment: Read the documentation of UICollectionView and what the exception is telling you; a UICollectionView needs a UIcollectionViewLayout; you need to provide one via the appropriate initialiser. You will also need to set constraints or the frames of your collection views. You are about to find that not using storyboards is a whole lot more work and, in my opinion, generally not worth the pain.

Comment: One obvious issue is the fact that you never set the frames of the collection views. Use the proper `init` method.

Comment: @Paulw11 don't find storyboards cumbersome to work with. The main use case I'm looking to use programatic swift to solve is to bring views to the front (like a zoom on a picture/detail modal type thing).  It seems lie animations and swapping views would be ideal for programmatic swift.

Comment: Where you want to add views dynamically then doing so programatically is typically the simplest approach, but it doesn't have to be all-or-nothing.  You can combine the two approaches.  Storyboard saves a lot of lines of code, but ultimately it is up to you.

Comment: @Paulw11 Cool, thanks.  I'll probably go down the road of programmatic, and then circle back to a hybrid approach.  I have heard that in terms of teams, full programmatic is more maintainable.  I am not working on a team however.

Comment: Merging changes made by different programmers in storyboards can be problematic and Xcode used to have a bug where even opening the storyboard file made a change to the file which caused havoc with version control.  This bug has been fixed and the ability to use multiple storyboards in a project has made storyboards less of an issue in team development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize a `UICollectionView` with no arguments. You need to provide a `collectionViewLayout` parameter so the collection view knows how to arrange its content.

Instead, create a layout object and use it to initialize the collection view. A nice way to do this in Swift is to use lazy closures to initialize properties.

```
public lazy var collectionViewShirts: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    // any other configuration here
    return collectionView
}()
```

Comment: You still need to give the collection view a valid frame so it is visible.

Comment: @rmaddy Yep! You also need to add it as a subview, implement the delegate and data source methods, etc. Trying to solve the asker's direct problem as quickly as possible since there are lots of other great answers and tutorials if they need a full solution.

Comment: @nathan I am trying to init it as visible. Do I change CGRect.zero to something else?

Comment: @user1093111 Yes, the `CGRect.zero` is more or less a placeholder. You will want to assign a frame to the collection view, either by specifying a `CGRect` value or by setting constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Just  add   UICollectionViewFlowLayout to your Collection View

```
 public var collectionViewShirts : UICollectionView{

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        return collectionView

    }
    public var collectionViewPants :UICollectionView{

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        return collectionView

    }
```